# How do I toggle link states when clicked with AJAX and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototype

In one of my index actions I want to display a link that says either "activate" or "de-activate", depending on whether the record is active or not.

When the user clicks on an "activate" or "de-activate" link for a particular record, a call should be made to my update action that updates the record accordingly, and if the link said "activate" it should be changed to "de-activate" and vice versa.

How might I achieve this? I've looked at `link_to_remote`, but I have no idea how I'm going to toggle the text for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view I put this:

```
<% for account in @accounts %>
  <tr id="<%= "update[#{account.id}]" %>">
    <%= render :partial => "account", :object => account %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In my update action I put this:

```
def update
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
      format.html do redirect_to(@account)
        flash[:notice] = 'Account was successfully updated.'
      end
      format.xml  { head :ok } 
      format.js   { render :partial => 'account' } 
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" } 
      format.xml  { render :xml => @account.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity } 
    end
  end
end
```

And in my partial I put this:

```
<td><%=h account.email %></td>
<td><%=h account.password %></td>
<td><%=h account.get_status %></td>
<td><%=h account.network.name %></td>
<td>
  <%=
    link_to_remote(
      # name
      account.get_status == :active ? 'De-activate' : 'Activate',
      # options = {}
      {
        :url =>
        {
          :controller => "accounts",
          :action => :update,
          :id => account.id,
          :account => { :status => account.get_status == :active ? account.find_status(:inactive) : account.find_status(:active) }
        },
        :method => :put,
        :update => "update[#{account.id}]",
      },
      {
        :with => "'account[status]=' + $('account['status']).value"
      }
    )
  %>
</td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(account) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', account, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

The docs aren't very clear on sending parameters from `link_to_remote` to your actions. The parameters you want to send to your update actions, you would put in the `options` hash of `link_to_remote`, and from this my records are successfully updated when the link is clicked.

Also, for the actual 'toggling' of the text of the link, a ternary condition in the `name` parameter of `link_to_remote` is what did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to use link_to_remote, you then have to respond to js format in your controller and send js code to be executed with page update:

```
  update_page do |page|
    page.replace_html 'link_id', "<a href='#'>OtherState</a>"
    page.visual_effect :highlight, 'link_id' # you can highlight the item to give more feedback to the user
  end
```

Comment: update_page isn't working for me. I don't think it's in my version of Rails (2.2.2). I've figured it out, though, thanks.